# How to restart automatically a song of a different app from my app?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I played a song from another music player, and I have my own app that plays an audio, for now I can pause the song once my app plays the audio with requestAudioFocus(), so I would like to get back the previous song to play it again when my audio finish, is there a way to do it? I think it is like when you are listening music and you received a call, the music stops, and when the call ends you can listen the music again.

Let me show you what I did so far.
First I played my favorite song on a music player(a different app)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmRtR.png)
Second I made my own app to play and audio file when the button is clicked
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Mq7.png)
and I use this code to stop my favorite music from my app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD6aU.png)
so then my favorite music is paused
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxBD1.png)
Finally What I want to get is my favorite song being autmatically played again.

Comment: you can't. it Music Player app responsiblity to resume song

Comment: So, how the phone call example works? it is like what I want to achieve.

Comment: Please show what you've tried and what you've searched to solve the issue...

Comment: I did it, I'm new here so I have no reputation, I left some links.

Comment: You can't influence on other apps. At least this way. For the music app to pause/resume music when some higher priority sound events come up (call, notification, etc) it has to listen to the audio focus events. But it is nothing you can do about it, only the *other app* should support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, so first notice u can't influence on other apps as Vlad said, I tested on two different apps, Google Play Music, and the default Radio, I was very happy to see the expected results.